# how to scale image according to image - css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am soo bad at css. I have a div in which multiple images can be put. this div is a slide.

```
<div id="slides">                  
   <img src="imagename.jpg"/>                                                                 
</div>
```

some images are e.g. 100x300 but some are 300x100. how can I scale those images according to their own dimensions so that they show up as in original form?

my live example with this bug is in here: 
http://wohne-wo-du-willst.de/angebot/Wohnung/ist-frei-in-Dachau/22/

as you slide, the 3rd slide image doesnot show up in its full form..

Comment: whats wrong with `img{width:100%;height:auto}`??

Comment: The images within your slides aren't 100x300 or 300x100, they're 1920x2560 or 2560x1920, and each around 1MB in size. If you want your images to be 100x300 or 300x100 you should ideally resize them before delivering them to allow them to load much faster on slower connections.

Comment: @NoobEditor, this should do the trick, but slide height doesnot scale, how do i do that?

Comment: use img{ height : 100%;width:100%;}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A big problem you have here is that your images *aren't* 100x300px or 300x100px, they're instead 1920x2560px or 2560x1920px - much, much larger. They're also all around 1MB in size, which in reality is far too large for images like this. Before doing anything you should resize these images yourself to make them their desired size and ultimately reduce their file size as well.

After that, simply remove the `max-width` and `max-height` properties from your `#slides img` selector, then modify `width` and `height` to:

```css
#slides img {
    ...
    height: initial;
    width: initial !important;
}
```

The `initial` value sets the image size to its initial size; that means if your image is 100x300, that is also its *initial* size. Using this with the images you currently have will set them to 1920x2560 or 2560x1920.

I've unfortunately had to use `!important` here as the slide plugin will try to force your images to 100% width.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
img
   {
      height:100%;
      width:100%;
    }
</style>

<div id="slides">                 
 <img src="imagename.jpg"/>                                                                 
</div>
```

Comment: See the comments above,  NoobEditor clearly asked whats wrong with `img{width:100%;height:auto}`??